# How do I find a == function in swift

Tags: swift

I'm looking for the overriden `==` function of a `Hashable` object. There doesn't seem to be a way to search by call hierachy when selecting a use of ==. How can I find where the function is defined?

Comment: What object? Do you have the source for this object?

Comment: @tadman Any object that I have the source for. We have a very large code base and there are many places where extensions are defined which could override the `==` function. Cleanup aside, how can I locate the overridden `==` function for my class?

Comment: If you're using Xcode you can probably use the function search tools to narrow down where to look. You could also use that in your code and "step into" in a debugger to find out precisely where.

Comment: @tadman I tried all that and could not step into an `==` function.

Comment: Selecting the “==” in the Xcode editor and “Navigate->Jump To Definition” should work.